# An Integral with Singularity in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-integration

I am trying to integrate the following function from 0 to Inf in MATLAB:

```
f = @(x)exp(-(1./(2.^x - 1)).^(0.5))
integral(f, 0 Inf)
```

I am getting this error:

> Warning: Minimum step size reached near x = 1.75484e+22. There may be
>   a singularity, or the tolerances may be too tight for this problem.

I know there is an error when x approaches infinity giving and integral of 1. I may be wrong. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: When x approaches infinity the integrand approaches 1. Your integral does not converge. You will only be able to integrate functions on an infinite interval if they tend to zero. Just use `plot(t,f(t))` for `t=linspace(0,1e4,1e4)` to check this.

Comment: Using symbolic math might be an alternative: `int(f(sym('x')),0,inf)` which returns the correct answer (`inf`)

Comment: @knedlsepp I see! Is there a way to make this work? I have already stated in the question that I know the integrand approaches 1. I was hoping to see if I can integrate this with some other method or maybe just by changing the form of the integral to be integrable.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the hint but what does symbolic mean? I don't have that in my MATLAB.

Comment: The symbolic math toolbox adds [symbolic computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_computation) to matlab.

Comment: @KenProj: I don't understand what you mean by *making it work*. The function is not integrable (meaning: There is no finite value that can be meaningfully applied to it.). You could of course mean that `Inf` should be returned, but I don't see how this is a better result than the warning.

Comment: @KenProj I assume that you are using the Riemann integral? Then, by looking at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral) the integral converges if the riemann sum of the funciton converges. This means that the integral must be finite valued to exist. Your integral will converge towards 1*Inf= inf which is not finite